# Resizing all pictures, bigger than a given size with macro in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, pictures, resizing

I have a Word document with some 5000 pictures. There are two types, ones, that have low height, and others, which are higher. I only want to resize the ones higher than 1 cm to have a width of 2.3 cm. I have macro to resize all the pics, but if there is a way to add condition, which I mentioned, please let me know.

Here is the macro, I used for resizing all images.

```
Sub SizeAllImage()
Dim pic As Long
With ActiveDocument
For pic = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
    With .InlineShapes(pic)
        .Width = CentimetersToPoints(2.3)
    End With
Next pic
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What if you add an IF test to check if height of picture is >=1cm, with the true result being the .Width assignment in your With block. For example, assuming .height is already in points:  if .Height>=CentimetersToPoints(1) then .Width=CentimetersToPoints(2.3) –

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm. Will you make the answer for this, or should I?

To people not really familiar with the vba syntax, here's the final macro, that worked for me:

    Sub SizeAllImage()
    Dim pic As Long
    With ActiveDocument
    For pic = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        With .InlineShapes(pic)
        If .Height >= CentimetersToPoints(1) Then
           .Width = CentimetersToPoints(4.3)
           End If
        End With
    Next pic
    End With
    End Sub

Comment: Happy for you to add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to create this conditional macro is this, using an If to check for the heigth of the selected image. (thanks for the help to Tanya).

```
Sub SizeAllImage()
Dim pic As Long
With ActiveDocument
For pic = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
    With .InlineShapes(pic)
 If .Height >= CentimetersToPoints(1) Then
    .Width = CentimetersToPoints(2.3)
End If    
End With
Next pic
End With
End Sub
```